# Recaptcha - Does not show validation image

Tags: recaptcha

I click on "I am not Robot" Checkbox. The Validation is successful,it simply accepts me as a human, without prompting validation image.  Couple of days back when i was testing recaptcha everything was working fine. i.e it was prompting validation image. I tried disabling plugins on chrome but no luck. Any idea why no image shows up ? Thanks!

Comment: This behavior is by design.

Comment: Isnt recaptcha suppose to prompt for validation image text, when user clicks on i am not robot checkbox ?

Comment: http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html

Comment: I also don't understand whats happening here, on why after a significant amount of users the captcha will be just a check and no puzzle required?

Answer (score 4):

It is not mandatory that Google  Recaptcha will always prompt you to select images for verifying.This version 2 of Recaptcha is made to solve the purpose of not selecting images or not giving too much input from the user. Most of the time it validates by clicking the I Am not robot check box , if in case it fails it prompt image validation..
I hope it will clear your doubt.

Comment: I also don't understand whats happening here, on why after a significant amount of users the captcha will be just a check and no puzzle required?

Comment: It's not just a checkbox, there's a whole lot of code checking the mouse movements of a user. A human moves the mouse differently to a robot and Google uses that data.

Comment: @VincePanuccio yeah correctly mentioned the mouse movement point

Answer (score 3):

```html
data-type="image"
```

is ok! And do not forget check it in incognito window.

Answer (score 2):

add data-type
data type for recaptcha challenges edither may be image or audio but the default data-type is image.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-type="image" data-sitekey="some-key (original is right)">
```

Comment: not working still

Comment: Did u find any solution for this